# Which preposition follows "lack of knowledge"?

Tags: prepositions

I have the sentence

> Please excuse my lack of knowledge [preposition] proper essay formatting.

Should I write "lack of knowledge *in* proper essay formatting" or "lack of knowledge *on* proper essay formatting"? I cannot figure out which is correct.

Comment: With or without "*lack of*", the word "*knowledge*" takes the preposition "*of*".

Answer (score 2):

As Dan Bron pointed out in his comment, the logical choice is **of**.

"in" is not bad; "on" is inconceivable.

Answer (score 1):

"In" would be the proper choice, as "essay formatting" is a subject *in which* one may have knowledge, but it's always preferable to use only as many words as you need to get your point across, and a preposition isn't really necessary in this case. So skip the preposition: "Please excuse my lack of proper essay formatting knowledge."

Comment: essay-formatting knowlege

Comment: Hello and welcome to EL&U, Brandon Wandersee. Please consider expanding your answer slightly to include one or two reference works that support your conclusions. This will strengthen your answer and give the questioner an authoritative source to consult for further information. Thanks!

Comment: @BrianHitchcock: The hyphen seems inappropriate here. Hyphenation transforms it into an adjective directed at the subject "knowledge"---as in "Knowledge that is essay-formatting." The knowledge itself doesn't format the essay, though.

Comment: It is knowlege ABOUT formatting essays. That's what kind of knowlege it is. Hence, adjective. Without the hyphen, it says the essay formats the knowledge.